# References to Lupin 3rd in Netflix's Lupin series?

Tags: reference, lupin

I just finished watching Lupin "In the shadow of Arsène" series by Netflix.

The series is manifestly inspired to [Arsène Lupin, portrayed in the novels by Maurice Leblanc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars%C3%A8ne_Lupin).

While in the plot there is no mention *ever* of the (more popular????) [Lupin 3rd, nephew to Arsène](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars%C3%A8ne_Lupin_III) character from the <strike>comic/cartoon</strike> manga/anime series, I am curious to ask if the authors of Lupin series took inspiration/influence from Lupin 3rd, as I could find at least a couple of connections.

Are there any references to Lupin 3rd in the series?

Answer (score 1):

## Benjamin's car

Lupin the 3rd's gang notably owns an iconic yellow Fiat 500 driven by Jigen Daisuke.
[image: Cosplayers playing Lupin's gang with their iconic car]
In the Lupin series, at some point Benjamin is portrayed driving an identical car. Judging from the epoch of the novels, I **seriously** exclude that Arsène Lupin 1st could drive any sort of car.

## Cop chase

One of the iconic recurring scenes in Lupin 3rd is the awkward chase by a large number of cops sent by Mr. Zenigata. In the scene...

> final of episode 10...

... Assane Diop is chased by a large number of Paris cops (`Police Nationale`/`Gendarmerie`) who can't catch him

Having not (yet) read the novels, I don't know if Lupin 1st is chased by many cops, and if those chases are portrayed *awkwardly* as in the anime.